# Arithmetic comparison to avoid floating point errors

Tags: java, floating-point

I have the following check in one of my Java functions...

```
return floor(value * 100.) % 5 == 0;
```

I've been told that there is a potential for floating point errors because I am comparing raw values using `==` but I cannot see why. I thought that using `floor` would avoid that. Why might there be a floating point error and what is the best practice in this case to avoid such errors?

Comment: What is `value`? what error you got?

Comment: @YCF_L it is a double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's a mistake we (Java developers) often make, but in general it can be observed in *almost* all programming languages — at least the ones I use these days.

The entire thing boils down to how those values are stored in memory — if I'm not mistaken, in Java, `float`s and `double`s are stored using the `IEEE 754` standard format.

Anyway, instead of using the equality operator (`==`), we should rely on relational operators: less than (`<`) or greater than (`>`) to compare `float` and `double` values, because in the end, floating point numbers *are just an approximation*, they are not exact.

Another approach (I personally like) is to use `Float.compare` / `Double.compare`, if you are more familiar with the semantics of `compareTo`-kind of comparisons.

> Alternatively, I sometimes use also `BigDecimal` for exact calculations.

Comment: Re “floating point numbers *are just an approximation*, they are not exact”: Per the IEEE-754 floating-point specification, each floating-point datum other than a NaN represents one number **exactly**; it is not an approximation. It is the floating-point operations, not the numbers, that approximate real arithmetic. (Operations include converting decimal numerals to floating-point and vice-versa.) This distinction is essential for understanding floating-point arithmetic, for designing good floating-point software, and for writing proofs about floating-point software.

Comment: `<` and `>` are not any more free of problems than `==` is; they are also discontinuous functions that experience jumps from small errors. E.g., attempting to test whether `value < 4` will give an undesired result if value is near 3.9999999999 due to floating-point rounding errors, but the ideal real-arithmetic result would have been 4.

Comment: I think you are mixing things here. Real numbers are not approximations, of course, but the same representation by a computer system is indeed an approximation to those real numbers. I hope that clears it. On the other hand, if you have time, I would really like to see a close-to-real like code example where `<` and/or `>` is not accurate, within their boundaries. You can share it via: https://repl.it/

Comment: No, a IEEE-754 floating-point datum on a computer system is not an approximation. As I stated, the IEEE-754 standard specifies that, if it is not a NaN, it represents one number, exactly (IEEE 754-2008 clauses 3.3, 3.4, and 3.5). Some programmers use floating-point features as if the numbers were approximate, but this is generally due to ignorance of the specification and causes problems. It would be infeasible for an IEEE-754 datum to represent some approximation, as then the results of further operations could not have good definitions, due to smearing of the range.

Comment: As for `<` and `>`, I did not say they were not accurate, I said they were not any more free of problems than `==` is. They are in fact perfectly accurate: `<`, `>`, and `==` always return true if and only if the left operand is less than, greater than, or equal to the right operand, with no error. The problem they have is they are discontinuous, and so they magnify small errors that already exist in their inputs, although they never introduce new errors. As for an example, I already gave you one. If we have a `value` that would be 4 with real arithmetic but is near 3.9999999999 due to…

Comment: … errors in prior computations, then `value < 4` produces true when ideally it would produce false. This is exactly the same problem that occurs with `==`: If `value` would be 4 but is near 3.9999999999, then `value == 4` produces false when ideally it would produce true.

Comment: One of the things that may lead some programmers to think floating-point numbers are approximations is they enter a decimal numeral, say 3.4, in their source code or input, and the result of converting it to floating-point is 3.399999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375. Most are not actually aware of that at first, because default formatting may actually show 3.4. And eventually they become aware the number is not quite 3.4, because it acts somewhat like 3.4 but idiosyncrasies become visible from time to time. And they just go with it; the software shows them 3.4, so it is sort of…

Comment: … 3.4 but is an approximation, and they live with it. That is an unfortunate way to learn. You cannot write proofs based on “well, the thing is kind of like a number.” The proper model here is not that the result of “3.4” in input is some approximation of 3.4. The proper model is that the conversion itself is an operation (IEEE-754 5.4.3) and behaves as most operations do: The result of this floating-point operation is the exact mathematical result rounded to the nearest representable number. So it produces one specific number, not an approximation, and error has been introduced…

Comment: … Conversion from floating-point to decimal, as for output, as also an operation. Once you use this model, it becomes possible to write proofs about floating-point software and to design floating-point software to meet specific requirements.

Answer (score 4):

> Why might there be a floating point error…

There are three potential places for floating-point error in the expression you show:

- `value` is presumably the result of prior computations, and those might have had errors. We have no information about those, since you have not shown them.
- The code suggests there is some interest in `value` as some number of hundredths: .01, .02, .03, and so on. Except for .00, .25, .50, and .75, no hundredths are representable in the binary floating-point format Java uses. So, even if prior computations were done as accurately as possible, the final result cannot possibly equal any number of hundredths other than .00, .25, .50, or .75. They will be at least slightly higher or lower. If they are lower, then multiplying by 100 and taking the `floor` may produce a value one lower than you desire.
- When `value` is multiplied by 100, if the result is not exactly representable (which it may not be because `value` may have 53 significant bits and 100 has 5 significant bits, so the product may have 58 significant bits, but only 53 can be represented in Java’s `double` format), then it is rounded to the nearest representable value.

Floating-point arithmetic is largely designed to **approximate** real arithmetic. For this purpose, it is generally good with continuous functions, such as multiplication, sine, and so on. Often, with continuous functions small errors in calculation produce small errors in results. However, `floor`, `%`, and `==` are discontinuous functions: They have places where some changes in the inputs cause jumps in the outputs. For floor, a small change from 3.99 to 4 causes a jump of 1 in the output. For `%`, a small change from `3.99 % 4` to `4 % 4` causes a jump of nearly 4. For `==`, a small change from `3.99 == 4` to `4 == 4` causes a jump from `false` to `true`.

> … what is the best practice in this case to avoid such errors?

By and large, the best practice when you need exact results for computations involving `%` is to use integer arithmetic or to use floating-point with care to ensure all operations are exact (as by doing integer arithmetic within the bounds where floating-point represents all integers, −2<sup>53</sup> to +2<sup>53</sup> for Java `double`). If you need to work around that, then there is no single best practice; good solutions would depend on what you are doing to obtain `value` and what results you are trying to achieve.